# Self signing an SSL certificate - does CN need to be where the certificate is going to be located (the URL of my app)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, azure, self-signed

I really don't know much about SSL.  I have an app up on Azure that I need to put SSL on.  I've been following the tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/enable-ssl/.

**My specific question is:** I created the self-signed certificate through IIS on my local machine and it automatically put the "Issued To:" value as the computer that I created this certificate on, my local machine name.  I didn't have any option to change it.  So, when creating a self-signed certificate, does the "Issued To: (CN)" need to be the domain of my app on Azure in order for it to work?  Would I need to create this certificate on the machine that will be hosting my app?

Comment: The CN needs to match the hostname you're going to be serving the site as. If your cert is for "foo.com", but you're actually serving up "bar.com", then you're going to get even louder security warnings from browsers than you do with a mere self-signed cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-signed certificates are handled differently by different clients. I don't think there's a general rule.

For example, if you connect Firefox to a site using your self-signed certificate, you can add an exception that will be tied to that particular host name. It's the same exception you can use for certificate that is trusted via a known CA, but for a different website. Effectively, the Firefox exception mechanism does both at once: each exception will be for a combination of target host name and specific certificate.

This is certainly not the case for all "exception" mechanisms you'd use to handle a self-signed certificate. For example, adding a certificate to your truststore in Java might make it trusted, but your Java application would still verify the hostname (if it's implemented correctly).

The status of self-signed certificates is problematic in general.

If for some reason you can't use a certificate from a well-known CA, using your own CA would probably be a better option than using a self-signed certificate directly. This should at least allow you to have a more realistic environment (especially regarding the two concerns of checking the authenticity of the cert itself and the identity of the cert) when you want to switch to another CA later on.

I don't know whether there's a good way to do all this within IIS, but there are tools that can help you with this. XCA comes to mind. You should then be able to export your host certificate in PKCS#12 format (p12/pfx) and import it into IIS, as well as exporting your CA certificate in PEM format and import it in your clients.